# AWS CloudTrail log fie cannot be unzipped

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, 7zip, amazon-cloudtrail

I downloaded a cloud trail GZ file from my S3 bucket, but when i tried to unzip it using the freshly downloaded 7zip, the error message says "cannot open file xxx as archive". I tried to save the log in different S3 buckets. I deleted the trail and recreated it. I tried stop the trail then download it. It is always the same. What's going on?

Comment: if you use command line then simply use `unzip` command with your file name.

Comment: How did you download the .gz file? I've noticed that when I download it via the S3 Management Console, it is already unzipped. Take a look at the file in a text editor and see whether it appears as normal JSON content.

Comment: Thank you John! You are right. It is already unzipped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My testing has shown that downloading the `.gz` file within the Amazon S3 console actually saves an unzipped version of the file. Notice that the file extension will present the gzipped file, rather than being of type `.gz`.

I think this is because browsers can handle HTML files compressed in `.gz` format, so they natively decompress such files.

Comment: Broswers don't automatically handle `.gz` *files* but they do automatically handle `Content-Encoding: gzip`. This is unfortunately incorrect design behavior on the part of CloudTrail, but it's a mistake I see people make:  the objects are stored in S3 with `Content-Encoding: gzip`.  It is fundamentally incorrect to do both that *and* give the file a `.gz` extension **unless** the object has been gzipped *twice*, which there is of course no reason to ever do.  For a `.gz` file to be *downloadable as a `.gz` file*, `Content-Encoding` is blank and `Content-Type` is `application/gzip` or similar.

Comment: ...in the current situation, the files should have been created with only a `.json` extension and the `Content-Type` and `Content-Encoding` set as they are now, because the gzipping is not of the *file* per se but rather of the HTTP *representation* of the entity -- a JSON document.  Adding `.gz` creates a significant and avoidable ambiguity.